# Como Tirar dados de uma tabela SQL, referenciando apenas a primeira posição do tipo VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Preciso eliminar tudo que começa com '9' na minha coluna seg1, por exemplo:

Se na tabela esta '954747A' vai ser eliminado pois o 9 é a primeira posição.

Caso tenha '34465922A' Não tem que ser eliminado.

A logica que eu estava fazendo esta matando tudo relacionado a 9.

Segue Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.SEG1 ||'-'|| a.SEG2 ||'-'|| A.SEG3
FROM TB_TESTE
WHERE A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%C%'   
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%D%' 
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%E%' 
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%F%'  
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%G%' 
   AND A.SEG1 NOT LIKE '%9%';
```

Comment: Poderia colocar como ele retorna, e o que esta relacionado na SEG1? aonde esta esses numeros que voce quer eliminar, pois no caso iria um notlike"%9" no caso

Comment: DELETE FROM TB_TESTE WHERE SEG1 LIKE '9%';

Comment: @anonimo eu não posso deletar tudo da tabela eu coloquei só uma abreviação de nome da tabela agora como exemplo.

Comment: @anonimo é uma tabela importante, eu to fazendo esta regra só para esse sistema. mas em outros é usado normalmente. mas obg pela ajuda

Comment: Mas o comando acima está de acordo com o que você afirmou em "Preciso eliminar tudo que começa com '9' na minha coluna seg1". A não ser que com "eliminar" você queira dizer "não recuperar", neste caso substitua o DELETE por SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo desse genero pois o `LIKE` com a `%` no comeco irá pegar apenas as que comecam

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.SEG1 ||'-'|| a.SEG2 ||'-'|| A.SEG3
FROM TB_TESTE
WHERE A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%C%'   
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%D%' 
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%E%' 
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%F%'  
   AND A.SEG3 NOT LIKE '%G%' 
   AND A.SEG1 NOT LIKE '%9';
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Não sei nem como agradecer

Comment: se puder colocar como resposta correta, kkk fico feli em ajudar :)

Comment: Feito meu amigo, eu só não to conseguindo avaliar :( se não te dava 1 ponto